# Slide in div with fixed position with Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, slide, fixed

I have a Scroll to top button with a Fixed position.
I want this button to slide in from the bottom of the screen after you scrolled 400px.
i can get it to work with fadein and fadeout.
This is the code of the button.

```
<a href="#top" id="scrolltop"><img src="images/upbutton.png" alt="scroll to top"/></a>

#scrolltop {
position:fixed;
height:38px;
width:38px;
background-color:#444;
right:15px;
bottom:15px;
z-index:100;
} 



$(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 1000) {
            $('#scrolltop').animate({bottom: 100});
        } else {
            $('#scrolltop').animate({bottom: -100});
        }
});
```

Comment: What's the question? Please show your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that your are testing against 1000 instead of 400.

Besides that the `scroll` event is fired multiple times while scrolling. And because the `animate` function of jquery is stackable you end with multiple animations in each direction and long delays while waiting for each to end..

So you need a more strict logic..

- do not animate if the element is already animating, use the [`:animated` jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector) combined with the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is)
- also check if the element is already in the correct place before trying to animate towards it,  add/remove a `class` as a flag to do this
- also it is a good idea to cache variables that you repeatedly use

so the script becomes

```
var scr = $('#scrolltop');
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        if (scr.is('.off') && !scr.is(':animated')) {
            scr.animate({bottom: 100}, function () {
                scr.removeClass('off');
            });
        }
    } else {
        if ((!scr.is('.off')) && (!scr.is(':animated'))) {
            scr.animate({bottom: -100}, function () {
                scr.addClass('off');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7eYdB/